# In Hazelcast, when using distributed locks as a client, will the lock be freed when the client disconnects?

Tags: locking, hazelcast

The Hazelcast documentation shows that you can use a distributed Hazelcast as a client and mentions that if a member holding the lock gets disconnected - the lock will be released. However, if I am using the lock as a client this will not count as a "member" - will the lock still safely be released if the client gets disconnected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client lock will automatically be released. Try the following program and you will see yourself.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        HazelcastInstance hz1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();

        client.getLock("clientLock").lock();
        System.out.println("is locked:" + hz1.getLock("clientLock").isLocked());

        client.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Client is shutdown");
        for(;;){
            boolean isLocked = hz1.getLock("clientLock").isLocked();
            if(!isLocked){
                System.out.println("Client lock is released");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("is locked:"+ isLocked);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This example is if you shut down gracefully. But we have clients that are effectively dying, and the lock still remains. Is there a "correct" way to handle this on the hazelcast cluster?